# Microsoft Word restores all open documents when clicking on a .DOC file

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I tend to have a few Word documents that I keep open all the time, with notes for a long-running project. Normally they are all minimized.

The problem is that when I click on a different `.doc` or `.docx` file in Windows Explorer, even though the new document opens in its own window, the other, minimized Word documents get restored, too. Now I have several restored windows that I wanted to keep minimized.

I started noticing this problem on Windows 7, but I'm not sure if it's unique to Windows 7. I'm using Word 2007.

Comment: I have almost the same behaviour in Win7 RC1 though only one of the minimised docs is restored. Similarly with Excel 2007, opening a spreadsheet in Explorer briefly displays a minimised spreadsheet which is then hidden by the newly opened one until that is closed, when it is left restored. 
Anyone know if this still happens with Win 7 RTM?

Comment: Just boot into OS X - works fine there :P

Comment: It is now year 2020 and Word has had this problem for 10 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this problem by blocking Word from using DDE to open files.

In the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open` key:

- Delete or rename the `ddeexec` sub-key

In the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\command` key:

- Delete or rename the `command` **value** (not to be confused with the command key.)
- Edit the (Default) value and add `"%1"` (including quotes) at the end

This solves the problem for `.docx` files. If you also want to solve it for `.doc` files, do the same thing for `Word.Document.8`

Thanks to: [Rafael's Within Windows](http://www.withinwindows.com/2008/08/31/taming-microsoft-word-2007s-file-associations-and-document-windows-part-one/) which has detailed instructions.

Comment: Rafeal's new blog doesn't seem to have this, nor could I find mirrors anywhere.  The Archive.org link is: https://web.archive.org/web/20120722030435/http://www.withinwindows.com/2008/09/03/taming-microsoft-word-2007s-file-associations-and-document-windows-part-two/

Answer (score 1):

In Vista at least, if you have multiple Word windows minimized and double click to open a document in Windows Explorer, it will (apparently) randomly pick ONE of the minimized windows to pop open.

This behavior is a little bit different than Joel describes above for Win7

Answer (score 1):

I found another RegEdit [solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20190425175356/https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fcf07dd3-12b6-4ce5-b216-330b7ad0b76b/force-word-to-start-each-document-in-separate-process?forum=word), which works for me:

1. In the Windows Start Menue search for RegEdit and start the Registry Editor
2. Search for: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\command
3. Now you add “/w” parameter in registry, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I tested it with Word 365 in Windows 10, successfully.

Comment: worked for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually an answer, but rather a workaround.

There's an option under "Word Options / Advanced / Display", named "Show all windows in the taskbar". Turning it off hides all Word icons in the taskbar but one. This way, the described behavior disappears, but at the same time, also the ease of restoring a minimized document.

The only way to browse between the open documents is now with the "Switch windows" button under the "View" menu.

[image]

**Edit:** I did the test on MS Vista, as I don't have a Windows 7 machine at work.

**Edit #2:** I can confirm that the behavior after turning off "Show all windows in the taskbar" is the same also on Windows 7.