# How to suppress Microsoft Word to restore a minimized Word documents when opening another one?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I tend to have multiple Word documents open at the same time, which are minimized. When I now open a new Word document, one of the minimized documents gets restored and pops up, before the new document shows up as well.

I have been following [this instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/19586/microsoft-word-restores-all-open-documents-when-clicking-on-a-doc-file) (answer from Joel) to solve this problem, but either the solution does not work, or I am doing something wrong. I am also not quite sure to understand the given instructions, as one should rename/delete a value and then add something to it:

- Delete or rename the `command` **value** (not to be confused with the command key.)
- Edit the (Default) value and add `"%1"` (including quotes) at the end

Also, I am confused with 'key' and 'value' especially since I am using unfortunately a German Windows 7 installation. [image].

Does 'Name' correspond to 'key'? Does 'Daten' correspond to 'value'? How to interpret the instructions given by Joel? If I remove the line 'command' on the right side in the screen shot, how to edit its value then? This does not make much sense to me.

Maybe this is the wrong approach at all? What can I do to avoid a minimized Word document to pop up when opening a new Word document?

Comment: The described approach is useless, because Word is no longer invoked with the `/dde` parameter.

Comment: @harrymc: You have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: If I knew I would have used it already. It's a Windows problem, not anything to do specifically with Word. It also happens with other programs when one opens the program more than once. And it dates from more than a decade ago.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me although it may have unintended consequences.

Open regedit and edit the following key:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\command(Default)

Replace the parameters with `"%1" /x`

e.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" "%1" /x`

Answer (score 0):

A registry key refers to any of the items in the left hand window of your screenshot, these are the identifiers. The right hand window lists any given values for a key that you have currently selected, as you can see there are two values for the command key. There is always a default value for a key.

In this case the instructions suggest you to:

1. Remove the command value (from the right hand window, right click
   that entry and click **Delete**)
2. Modify the default value (in your locale this is called
   **Standard**). Right click on the value in the right hand window and choose the first option from the drop down list, it should be something that resembles
   "**Modify.**.".
3. From there you will see a tiny dialog box where you can edit the
   value. The data already populated in this text box should resemble a
   file path. At the end of this path add "%1" including the quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. However, the proposed procedure still does not change the behaviour of opening docx documents. A document, which is minimized, will restored on the screen, before the document appears I am opening. Maybe I need to restart the computer or something for the changes to take effect?

Comment: @Alex, It can never hurt :) Make sure you have deleted the ddeexec subkey as well.

Comment: Reboot did not change anything. Minimized document still pops up.