# When I open an MS Word document, any minimized Word document then pops up too

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word

In Windows-7, I open one or more Word docs.
I minimize everything (window-M).
I now open another Word doc.
One of the minimized instances always pops up along with the new one.
Really annoying because the minimized is sometimes on top of the new.

Sometimes, I just want to minimize everything and just focus on the Word doc that I just opened.

Comment: I was able to recreate this, very odd behavior....

Comment: What version of word do you have?

Comment: Actually this is a duplicate if you are using Office 2007 http://superuser.com/questions/19586/microsoft-word-restores-all-open-documents-when-clicking-on-a-doc-file

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to solve the same issue with Word 2016, but the key value mentioned in [Cosco Tech solution](https://superuser.com/a/1114633/912560) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE" /n **"%1"** /o "%u" was already present there. What I found though is, that adding /q switch to the default command registry key value prevents both:

1. Word splash screen on document opening
2. Maximization of currently minimized Word (.docx) documents.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for Office 2007

Open Regedit
Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open`
Rename the `ddeexec` sub key to `ddeexec.old`
Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12\shell\Open\command`
rename the `command` string to `command.old`
Edit the `Default` value and add `"%1"` to the end (including the quotes)
You do not need to restart for this to take effect
This will fix .docx
To resolve the issue for .doc navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\Open` and repeat the same procedure.
Now you can open documents without maximizing a previously minimized doc.

Source: [How do I prevent Word from redisplaying multiple minimized open documents when opening a new document?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/how-do-i-prevent-word-from-redisplaying-multiple/3b7594f1-0c1e-4108-9d5f-ced532781812?auth=1)

The link also contains a reg hack for office 2013 on the first page. I was unable to test, so I won't post it here.